# Is there a better way to loop through this object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JSON

```
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};
```

JS

```
for (k in data) {

  for (x in data[k]) {
    var cObj = data[k][x];

    $("#list").append(
      "<li><p>" + x + "</p></li>"
    );

    for (var i=0; i < cObj.length; i++) {
      $("#list").append(
        "<div> " + cObj[i].name + " </div>"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the expected result. But I feel like I'm using too many for loops. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aestheticdrift/q6uwy87h/6/) example.

Comment: Look into [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: `.append()` works with arrays, so it's possible to reduce the function to a single `forEach()` loop. See my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to find a way to reduce it to one loop but you can reduce it to two, and improve readability (as was already mentioned in a previous answer).

```
$.each(data.countries, function(continent, countries){

  $("#list").append(
      "<li><p>" + continent + "</p></li>"
  );

  $.each(countries, function(index, country){
    $("#list").append(
        "<div> " + country.name + " </div>"
    );
  })

})
```

[Here is an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6uwy87h/9/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer loop since there's only one property.

The innermost loop can be replaced by using `.map()` to get the names of the countries and `.join()` to link them with the proper HTML (also adding the opening and closing `div` before and after the `map/join` call).

```js
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};


for (const x in data.countries) {
  const cObj = data.countries[x];

  $("#list").append(
    "<li><p>" + x + "</p><div>" +
    cObj.map(c => c.name).join("</div><div>") +
    "</div></li>"
  );
}
```

```css
#list > li > p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#list > li > div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id=list></ul>
```

Note that you were putting `div` elements directly inside a `ul` element, which is semantically incorrect. You should instead close the `li` after the `div` elements are generated.

---

Here's one that replaces the `for-in` with `Object.entries()` and `.reduce()` so as to limit the number of DOM selection calls. It also uses template literals and parameter destructuring to clean things up.

```js
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};


$("#list").append(
  Object.entries(data.countries).reduce((res, [x, a]) =>
    res + `<li>
             <p>${x}</p>
             <div>${a.map(c => c.name).join('</div><div>')}</div>
           </li>`, "")
);
```

```css
#list > li > p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#list > li > div {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id=list></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice for you would be get rid of naked loops! They really make code harder to read. Instead utilise `forEach`, `map` etc. functions. Take a look at this snippet using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};

Object.keys(data.countries).forEach(function (continent) {
  var countryList = data.countries[continent];
  $("#list").append("<li><p>" + continent + "</p></li>");
  countryList.forEach(function (countryObj) {
    $("#list li").append("<div>" + countryObj.name + "</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

With good naming convention it does look more readable, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6uwy87h/10/http://) for you. This should be more performant than your original post,

```
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};
const continents = Object.keys(data.countries);
for (let j = 0; j < continents.length; j += 1) {

    $("#list").append(
      "<li><p>" + continents[j] + "</p></li>"
    );

    let countries = Object.values(data.countries[continents[j]]);

    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i += 1) {
      $("#list").append(
        "<span> " + countries[i].name + " </span>"
      );
    }
  }
```

I like the other two answers better than mine, they look even more performant than mine and do less looping.

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of jQuery's `.append()`'s ability to accept arrays. This allows us to use a single `forEach` loop (with a `.map()` to wrap the countries in `<li>` tags).

Here it is in action:

```js
var data = {
  "countries": {
    "europe" : [{name: "England", abbr: "en"}, {name: "Spain", abbr: "es"}],
    "americas" : [{name: "Unites States"}],
    "asia" : [{name: "China"}]
  }
};

Object.keys(data.countries).forEach(country => {
  $("#list").append("<li><p>" + country + "</p></li>");
  $("#list").append(data.countries[country].map(place => "<div> " + place.name + " </div>"));
});

// Using arrow functions here but they could be replaced with standard callback function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

If desired, though I'm not sure it's more elegant, both pieces of content could be passed as arguments to a single `.append()` call, like this:

```
Object.keys(data.countries).forEach(country => {
  $("#list").append(
    "<li><p>" + country + "</p></li>",
    data.countries[country].map(place => "<div> " + place.name + "</div>")
  );
});
```